# problem in ns2 installation

Tags: software-installation

I was trying to use sudo apt-get install build-essentials.Following messages were given by the compiler

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package build-essentials
```

how to overcome this problem??

Answer (score 0):

The correct name of the package is `build-essential`. So run

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```